# Linux Hudson, Windows build

Tags: windows, linux, hudson

I have Hudson installed on Linux. Compiling and testing Linux releases works fine. But I would like to build and test also Windows releases using Visual Studio. I already have .bat script that runs building, but I don't know how can I connect it to Hudson.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just install Hudson on a Windows machine and have it build the same code set?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Slave launchers](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/All+Plugins+by+Topic#AllPluginsbyTopic-Slavelaunchersandcontrollers), for example:

- [ssh slaves](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/SSH+Slaves+plugin)
- [copy to slave](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin)

You may need to install an ssh server on your windows computer.